# When to use vuex (in Nuxt)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm about to create a Vue.js project (ex. online reminder) and it implemented with RESTful API. I know that Vuex is a state management pattern but i don't know when to use it, because in my idea right now is every time i gonna implement a feature which will call a service will also create a store for that. like example: `Authentication` Service to be called in the `Authentication Store`.

My pattern/structure:

```
 - Service : Call api
 - Store : Call Service
 - Component : Store (Dispatch action)
```

First question:
I am implemented login feature, then created a service login method. so my question is do i really need to create action login method in store?

Second question:
In what particular module/feature or in when to use the store Vuex ?

Comment: I think your approach is right. I use Vuex to save data I want to be persistent over the app life, and to be accessed from different pages/components, as for example, auth system as you mentioned.

Another example could be: You have a "latest news" block in every page, you can get that content in a nuxtServerInit action inside the store, and then save it as a state, then you can get it from every page without requesting that data again.

Comment: okay. and how about an action that call api/service one time and doesn’t use state or doesn't have data to save, does it still necessary to create action for that?

Comment: @SergioCerrutti vuex is not for persistence, this is the job of cookies/localStorage, an API or alike. For OP: what would the call do if you don't use neither store the result?

Comment: Hey @kissu, you are right, but I meant to be persistent inside the app, not a session for example. Stored data will be persistent if you don't refresh the page or misuse router/nuxt links. I think Vuex in this way is useful in a lot of circumstances, don't you?

Comment: @SergioCerrutti local or global state is still sitting in the browser if you don't hard refresh the page indeed. But it's volatile as any other variable you create in JS. Persistency is not a term to use here IMO because for me it's basically mean "I can survive a refresh and still be here".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand which issue Vuex solves: https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern

> Multiple views may depend on the same piece of state.
> Actions from different views may need to mutate the same piece of state.
> For problem one, passing props can be tedious for deeply nested components, and simply doesn't work for sibling components. For problem two, we often find ourselves resorting to solutions such as reaching for direct parent/child instance references or trying to mutate and synchronize multiple copies of the state via events. Both of these patterns are brittle and quickly lead to unmaintainable code.

> So why don't we extract the shared state out of the components, and manage it in a global singleton? With this, our component tree becomes a big "view", and any component can access the state or trigger actions, no matter where they are in the tree!

Vuex is basically helping you passing data globally without relying on `props` and `emit` all day long. And that's pretty much all.

---

If you have let's say a cart of grosseries, you may put this in Vuex because you can go around all your website and throw some items at it. Relying on local state would be to cumbersome to compute the final checkout.

If you are fetching 10 photos from an API for your homepage, it may not be really useful to have the ability to reach it anywhere in your app, hence overkill to pass it to Vuex. In that case, local state and some props/emit is probably enough.

So, at the end it all depends on how you want to organize your code, try to not get too overkill with it.

---

For your second question, it's opinion-based and it depends. So, the best is for you to try it out and see how it goes. Would be able to change afterwards if there is an issue.

Comment: if it is just for only one component or in just one page so it is not necessary to create/put it in store ?

Comment: @RainRain it may be indeed not needed. An absolute answer can be hard to give because you may have some complex logic at some point but you can always move from a local state to vuex or vice-versa.